# SQLite wrapper 1.0.77 and Entity Framework under .NET 4

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

We are developing a windows application on .NET 4, it uses SQLite database with .NET wrapper [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) and Entity Framework. On deployment machine it requires .NET 4 Client Profile.

The latest official release (1.0.66) of SQLite wraper is 2 years old. This version works with .NET 2.0 — 3.5, it's mean that we should force users to install 2 versions of .NET. Also it does not supports foreign keys.

There is also [unofficial release 1.0.77](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) which supports foreign keys, however, support of ORM (.NET Entity Framework) is broken in this version (It raises System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException).
I can see three ways to fix this issue:

1. Abandon the use of this wrapper and look for other options. What would you suggest?
2. Abandon the use of Entity Framework. This option is undesirable because it is old-school way and also require us to rewrite a lot and write more code and increate the likelihood of bugs.
3. Try to fix an issue with 1.0.77, but I have no idea how long it can take. What would you do in this situation? What other wrappers we should look at?

Comment: Did also happen to me with all that setup done, except for: * I had a 32-bit `System.Data.SQLite.dll` referenced, while building a 64-bit configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I understand how to let 1.0.77 *System.Data.SQLite* assembly to work **with** Entity Framework and **without** placing assembly to the GAC.

My first tries to connect SQLite 1.0.77 resulted in:

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException:  A null was returned after calling the 'GetService' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'.  The store provider might not be functioning correctly.

Code analysis showed to me that main assembly *System.Data.SQLite.dll* can't find *System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll*. The second assembly has been referenced in project and existed in output bin folder. But the error didn't disappeared.
Reflector showed that *System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll* has no public classes. So it will never load automatically to app domain because there is no code referencing it. So it must be only in GAC for correct working.
But nothing can deny us to load it manually to app domain! For example, at application start:

```
Assembly.Load("System.Data.SQLite.Linq");
```

And that's it!

Also, don't forget about adding this lines to your application config:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.77.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Hope my expierence will be usefull.